# Eu preciso declarar todas as classes em seus arquivos?

Tags: php

A minha duvida é se do jeito que estou planejando fazer é o correto:  criar uma classe com todas as minhas outras classes instanciadas nela, funciona?

```
  class Instancias {

  public $Instancias;
  public $CRUD;
  public $Metas;

  public function SetaClasses() {

    $this->Instancias = new Instancias;
    $this->CRUD = new CRUD;
    $this->Metas = new Metas;

  }

  public function SetouClasses() {

    return $this->SetaClasses();

  }
  }
```

Me desculpem os erros estou pelo celular e pra chamar cada classe usaria o `autoload` na index, assim só setaria os métodos nas suas devidas classes, podem dar um exemplo se possível?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Funcionar? Funciona.

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

O problema das pessoas quererem fazer algo orientado a objeto é o fato delas não quererem aprender programar orientado a objeto, elas só querem criar classes sem nexo para dizer que está na moda que foi criada. OOP é bom quando serve a um propósito, quando a pessoa entende porque está fazendo aquilo e traz uma vantagem clara e objetiva. Quase todo mundo que diz estar fazendo OOP não tem a menor ideia porque está fazendo aquilo.

Qual o propósito de querer fazer isto? Seria pelo fato que começou fazendo errado desde o princípio e criou classes onde elas não eram necessárias e que dificultou o código e agora quer consertar isso criando mais uma classe para facilitar o acesso ao erro?

Então não é melhor consertar o erro inicial?

O que está fazendo é uma forma muito clara que não precisa das classes que criou e que agora está tendo dificuldade para lidar com isso. Esta classe não tem uma função clara no projeto.

Os nomes das classes usadas já indicam que tem algo errado. Vamos até dizer que tem uma classe `CRUD` que faça sentido. Mas ela deveria ser abstrata, e aí as concretas derivariam dela para fazer o que de concreto espera dela. Essa classe abstrata forneceria a infraestrutura necessária e os contratos que toda classe CRUD do sistema precisa. E isto só faz sentido em aplicações complexas que é onde OOP brilha. Se é algo simples e uma classe `CRUD` muito simples direta resolve, então todas essas classes são complicações para melhorar nada.

Dá para perceber que o problema é que está criando coisas que não faz sentido?

Comece justificando a existência de cada classe, detalhando cada benefício de fazer assim e porque feito sem a classe ficaria pior. Considere as desvantagens de fazer desta forma.

Não é estranho você instanciar a classe dentro dela mesmo? Até existe caso para isto, mas este? Nem posso falar de `Metas` porque não sei o que é isto e não parece fazer sentido. Tem cara de misturar conceitos. Programar orientado a objeto é justamente ter um entendimento maior do que é o objeto.

Não dá para pensar em OOP de forma artificial, só dá para fazer com exemplos concretos. Um dos problemas dos livros que tentam ensinar isto é justamente porque trabalham com exemplos artificiais, que sempre ensinam errado, faz as pessoas acreditarem que importa o mecanismo e não o modelo correto.

Além de não estar nas regras darmos exemplos praticamente aleatórios, o exemplo só reforçaria o erro.